# Counting employees from one job level to another

Tags: sql, count

I have a snapshot of a dataset as follows:

```
effective_date  hire_date   name    job_level   direct_report
01.01.2018      01.01.2018  xyz        5            null
01.02.2018      01.01.2018  xyz        5            null
01.03.2018      01.01.2018  xyz        5            null
01.04.2018      01.01.2018  xyz        6            null
01.05.2018      01.01.2018  xyz        6            null
01.01.2018      01.02.2018  abc        5            null
01.02.2018      01.02.2018  abc        5            null
01.03.2018      01.02.2018  abc        5            null
01.04.2018      01.02.2018  abc        5            null
01.05.2018      01.02.2018  abc        5            null
```

- Effective date is an overview of info for each employee on a daily
  basis.
- Hire date is the date when an employee was hired
- Job level is the level at which employee stands on that particular day

I want to find out as to how many employees moved/promoted from level 5 to level 6 during this overall time?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Have you tried any queries so far? If so, please provide them. We're happy to help you learn, but SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: also, tag your DBMS. Syntax differences will change answers. sql-server?mysql? oracle? access? db2?

Comment: You'll want to look into OVER and PARTITION.  You could get all users that are level 6 with a simple query WHERE job_level = 6, but it will give you multiple results.  OVER and PARTITION will allow you to rank those rows so you can get the first day the user was level 6(logically when they were promoted).  Simply google this phrase "ms sql over partition by example" and find the example that illustrates it best for you.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed you want to COUNT how many are promoted to 6, not see WHEN they were promoted.  Sorry for that, but I hope it still helps you.

Comment: I tried running this query-  select a.preferred_name, a.job_level as previous_level, b.job_level as new_level
from Peepalytics_Staging.WD_COMBINED_DATA a
join Peepalytics_Staging.WD_COMBINED_DATA b
on datediff(a.effective_date, b.effective_date)=1
where b.job_level > a.job_level;

Comment: the issue here is i just want to have employees from level 5 to level 6...should i put a filter here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method that uses two levels of aggregation.  You can get the employees that were promoted by comparing the minimum date for "5" to the maximum date of "6":

```
select name
from t
where job_level in (5, 6)
group by name
having min(case where job_level = 5 then effective_date end) < max(case where job_level = 6 then effective_date end);
```

To count them:

```
select count(*)
from (select name
      from t
      where job_level in (5, 6)
      group by name
      having min(case where job_level = 5 then effective_date end) < max(case where job_level = 6 then effective_date end)
     ) x;
```

Alternatively, you can use `lag()`:

```
select count(distinct name)
from (select t.*, lag(job_level) over (partition by name order by effective_date) as prev_job_level
      from t
     ) t
where prev_job_level = 5 and job_level = 6;
```

The two are subtly different, but within the range of the ambiguity of the question.  For instance, the first would count 5 --> 4 --> 6, the second would not.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this definitely helped...i got stuck in the effective date clause.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
select count(distinct name) from employees e1
WHERE effective_date between '01.01.2018' and '01.05.2018'
And job_level = 5
and EXISTS (select * from employees e2 where e1.name = e2.name
           and e2.effective_date > e1.effective_date
            and e2.job_level = 6
           )
```